# Importing project created by PhoneGap into Webstorm

Tags: android, cordova, ant, phonegap-build, webstorm

[Well, I think an almost similar question was asked before, but the responses did not answer my question (in fact no answer was accepted in that thread). In this case I will appreciate detailed responses written with easy terminologies. Confession: I am pretty new with both PhoneGap and Webstorm.]

Getting to the point- I have installed ANT, Android SDK, node.js and PhoneGap. Next I created a project on CLI using the command "**cordova create**". What I want now is importing this project into Webstorm IDE to work further on it.

To clarify, I have tried "**cordova build android**" command. But it responds with a '*The provided path "..." is not an Android project*'.

Is there anything else that I may try? My target is to load this project on Webstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use PhoneGap plugin, please, read the tutorial: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/PhoneGap%2C+Cordova+and+Ionic

**Note1:** In the latest WebStorm 9 EAP PhoneGap plugin is bundled so you don't need step 1.

**Note2:** WebStorm 'new project' dialog a little different from the IDEA dialog.

**Note3:** If you need add existing PhoneGap project to WebStorm you can just use 'Open ...' quick start on the Welcome Screen.

**Other:**
Command 'cordova build android' can be started only after command 'cordova platform add android'.

Comment: Thanks! This tutorial is just what I needed. I actually needed the first step though, as I am using WebStorm 8.0.4.

Command 'cordova platform add android' is not working. It's asking for Android SDK 19, which I have already installed. Seems like somehow Cordova cannot find it.

Comment: You can run android executable and install android sdk from the manager window.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following paths to my (windows) path system variable:

```
.../ant/bin
.../android/.../sdk/platform-tools
.../android/.../sdk/platforms
.../android/.../sdk/tools
.../android/.../sdk
```

After that, it all worked fine

Comment: Thanks, but these were things I already had done when I posted here. The source of my trouble was that my version of `WebStorm` did not come with the `PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin` installed, so I just had to install it.